# When Click an Image QFrame Size Changes

Tags: python, pyqt, qlabel

Everything is OK in the first picture . 
[image]

There are `qlabels` that display images . When I click one of them, a size problem occured the top of the second picture .I don't understand  what is the problem ?
[image]

Comment: Can u explain more?...Not clear to me?..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not want your QLabel to resize try to set a fixed size.

For the height you can use: [`setFixedHeight(int n)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setFixedHeight)

I also advise you to read [Qt Layout Management](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html) if you haven't already.